# Atmega328P - PU Not Working Properly (Instability, goes to sleep mode after some usage)

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, atmega328p, 7805

I have successfully designed & tested a circuit using arduino uno for controlling a dc motor (MAX 50A,12V,SHORT-DUTY) By using a relay module and current sensor (configuration given in schematic). Then i tried to convert it into a PCB & designed a schematic (given below) & fabricated it, I use the same Micro controller (Atmega328p-pu) which i used in arduino board (program it using arduino uno & put it into PCB). when i tried to run it works for first cycle of my application (when i press switch 1-on & when current reach 5A have to off) but after 1st cycle Atmega328P-PU freezes & it does't get any input from switches (if i use arduino uno instead of Atmega328P-PU means it works well) , i have tried all the possibilities to make it work but failed. Help me!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any bypass capacitors on VCC, also the AtMega series tops out at 20MHz, your running 24MHz?

Comment: It looks like your 3.3V regulator doesn't have any input or output caps.

Comment: @MadHatter Sorry Sir , I used 16MHz only, i posted it wrongly, but where to add bypass capacitors? can you explain me sir?

Comment: @Tyler Yes sir , but i just removed 3.3v regulator , Still i have issues

Comment: Try putting a ceramic capacitor around 1-0.01 uF across the VCC and ground line as close to the AtMega power inputs as possible. Try soldering it to the bottom of the board onto the pins connected to the socket, may be easiest if this is a board you made.

Comment: Could you upload an image of the board of the cad screenshot so we can see the power runs?

Comment: @MadHatter Sir i think i have put bypass caps near 7805 regulator , is it the one you mentioned ?

Comment: You need one physically close to the AtMega to short high frequency noise to ground. The physical location is important.

Comment: @MadHatter sir i didn't have cad files, i just have photocopy of PCB only. in which relay & current sensor circuits are working well (i checked it using arduino uno) . i just posted that photocopy in question, please check sir

Comment: Yea, with the thin power traces and lack of ground plane, you really need a bypass capacitor right near the AtMega. My guess is when the motor is turning off it is making all kinds of noise on the ground line you also have connected to your AtMega. You also could consider putting capacitors right near the relay, to reduce the high frequency noise from the motor from reaching the rest of the board.

Comment: @MadHatter sir So i need to add a cap between VCC & GND, i will make this changes & will get back to you soon sir

Comment: @ashok: There are ladies here too.

Comment: @ashok Hearing "sir" feels like a joke. As if someone is ridiculing me. Even if I am a male. This is 2017, not 1817. - But hey, there's probably some males who would like to be called "Sir", but this is not the place for it.

Comment: @MadHatter oh sorry. & thank you so much, i will inform you soon

Comment: @HarrySvensson Sorry ...

Comment: @Transistor Sorry

Comment: @HarrySvensson ashok is likely not from the same general area as you, and customs for how to address people may be very different for them than they are for you. Also, English may not be their first language, and they're just trying to be polite. Please keep that in mind when you correct someone ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is you're inadvertently holding the micro in reset. Remove C3, and short its pads with a piece of wire so the only thing on the reset pin is R3. If you must have a cap on the reset pin, it should be from reset to ground.

Comment: I was going to mention this, but the AtMega as a ~10k internal pull-up on the reset. I guess in a noisy environment though this may not be enough...